# Anylogic: How to add "output" value to presentation of optimization experiment?

Tags: optimization, output, anylogic, presentation, experimental-design

In my Anylogic model I have an output that gets a value after simulation end (see picture 2). I want to add this output value to the presentation of an optimization experiment (see picture 1), so that it shows the output value of the Best iteration. Can anybody tell me how to add an output value to the presentation of an optimization experiment?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Manually. In the "After Simulation run" code section of your opt-experiment, you can access your output: If it lives on `Main`, you would be able to access it via `root.outputMAPE`.

So you need to check after each individual sim run, if you currently have best iteration. If so, you update a local variable in the optimization experiment and plot that:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I did what you said but the variable bestSoFar remains empty during and after the optimization experiment

Comment: You can easily replace calling `isCurrentSolutionBest()` with some custom code where you check yourself if you reached something "best". Just use another variable `bestSoFar` and check yourself :)